# Get text using selenium PhantomJS inside Span

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I tried to get text inside span using Seleniung webdriver PhantomJS. My code is like this :

```
href = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='_8mlbc _vbtk2 _t5r8b']")
for rt in href:
    rt.click()
    if href:
        name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_99ch8']/span").text
        # name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[a[@title='nike']]/span").text
        print(name)
```

In HTML :

```
<li class="_99ch8"><a class="_4zhc5 notranslate _ebg8h" title="nike" href="/nike/">nike</a><span><span>Nobody believed a boy from Madeira would make it to the stars. Except the boy from Madeira. </span><br><a href="/explore/tags/nike/">#nike</a><span> </span><a href="/explore/tags/soccer/">#soccer</a><span> </span><a href="/explore/tags/football/">#football</a><span> </span><a href="/explore/tags/cr7/">#CR7</a><span> </span><a href="/explore/tags/cristiano/">#Cristiano</a><span> </span><a href="/explore/tags/cristianoronaldo/">#CristianoRonaldo</a><span> </span><a href="/explore/tags/mercurial/">#Mercurial</a><span> </span><a href="/explore/tags/justdoit/">#justdoit</a></span></li>
```

I want try to get text inside span.

Comment: can you provide HTML

Comment: this the HTML, peter :

<li class="_69ch8"><a class="_4zhc5 notranslate _ebg8h" title="nike" href="/nike/">nike</a><span><span>Nobody believed a boy from Madeira would make it to the stars. Except the boy from Madeira. </span><br><a

Comment: Can you update your question with `HTML` code (use the "edit" button). Sample provided in comments doesn't seem to be complete. Also specify what is desired output you want to get

Comment: @StefaniJohnsson Can you consider sharing the concerned url and the manual steps you are trying to perform? Thanks

Comment: @Andersson i add HTML in the question

Comment: @DebanjanB I want get text inside span. I trid using driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='_99ch8']/span//text()"), But the value alwats null, just show []

Comment: @StefaniJohnsson Apparently that should be an easy task for any Selenium user. But you are using PhantomJS, so I may need the actual url & tthe exact element from which you need the text. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `XPath` expression that returns text node as it unacceptable option for `selenium`- selector should return `WebDriver` element only

Also note that class name of `li` seem to be dynamic, so you might use `title` attribute value of child anchor instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[a[@title='nike']]/span").text
```

*UPDATE*

The complete code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/nike/')

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/?taken-by=nike")]')
for link in links:
    link.click()
    wait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div/article")))
    print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[a[@title='nike']]/span").text)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='dialog']/button").click()
```

*UPDATE#2*

You can also simply grab the same text without opening each image:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img')
for img in links:
    print(img.get_attribute('alt'))
```

Comment: it's Still error for me. i will give you the condition my code.

Comment: There might be couple of reasons... Can you share page `URL` and tell what exactly you intend to do on that page?

Comment: I try to using seleniung to test javascript from Instagram, i tried to nike account. https://www.instagram.com/nike/. What i tried is, click the image after that instagram will show the image and caption of image, i want to get the caption of image.

Comment: Check updated answer. Note that this will return text from only currently visible articles. To get more you should scroll down page (using `Keys.END`) to trigger `XHR`.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i need webdriver using PhantomJS. Not Chrome or firefox. I try to not open the browser on selenium. @andersson

Comment: Oh.. I see. It seem that in `PhantomJS` `DOM` is slightly different than actual one. Check another update

Comment: This is working! Thank you so much @andersson, you are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all, if you want to go for a single element, you need to use `find_element_by_xpath()` method instead of `find_elements_by_xpath()` method to get to the element.

If you're using `find_elements_by_xpath()` then you need to use a looping statement for printing all the names that comes in the `name` variable.

Also, using the `.text` property of an element would give you the desired result.

Try this

```
   name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//li[@class='_69ch8']/span).text
   print(name)
```

Comment: Are you sure the /li[@class='_69ch8']/span is not string ?

Comment: I give sting to /li[@class='_69ch8']/span but still error.

'
  name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='_99ch8']/span").text

'